# Java stream short circuiting operations: Can we assume one by one processing?

Tags: java, java-stream, short-circuiting

The JavaDoc specifications about short circuiting operations only talk about infinite and finite streams and about the termination of these.

But I wonder if we can even safely assume that the elements will be processed in a "one-by-one" manner or in other words: Can we assume that there is not only short circuiting but even the least processing necessary to get the result?

For example:

```
Object first = list.stream().map(expensiveMappingFunction).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Now it would be very nice to know if I can be sure that **only exactly one element** will be processed as the mapping function may take a long time per element (or any other reason that I really only want to call it once). Otherwise I would go with the good old `empty()`-check and `iterator().next()`.

The JavaDoc does not seem to say anything about that specifically, so maybe we can't assume that.

But maybe there is some kind of "unofficial convention" like that.

Or maybe I just haven't understood Java streams quite enough yet and this is a dumb question (in which case you may gladly point it out!).

Comment: With your example, it will be a sequential stream, where elements are processed 1-by-1 (from `#stream` until reaching the terminal operation `#findFirst`). Where this guarantee breaks down is in parallel streams using `Stream#parallel`. In terms of guaranteeing "least processing necessary" - the streams will be processed until the condition specified by its terminal operation is fulfilled. So `#findFirst` will terminate the stream upon finding the first result. There's no intrinsic guarantee that a stream will be the most optimal solution.

Comment: @Rogue I should've mentioned "sequential" streams, as "parallel" streams is a whole different world to me. I was only asking because one MIGHT implement a terminal operation that takes - let's say - batches of 3 (for whatever reason). Just like the ArrayList has an arbitrary initial capacity (for good reasons) there may be terminal operations that take more than one element at once. And I was asking about if there may or may not be that kind of situation.

Comment: There are no terminal operations that take "more than 1 element at a time" in a sequential stream. This could be argued either way in the context of parallel streams - some collectors will collect "batches" of processed data and merge them before finalizing the result. The actual operation underpinning these collectors is, however, still a 1-to-1 operation of stream elements to their eventual container (i.e. they will still be processed one element after another).

Comment: There is no such guaranty. But there’s also no guaranty that the JVM implementer doesn’t insert an obsolete counting-to-one-million loop after each statement. You have to trust them to have the same goal as you, to implement things as efficient as possible and not doing something without a reason. Perhaps, a future version will use vectorization to process more than one element at once, however, it will surely be considered that such changes must not introduce unnecessary expensive evaluations of intermediate steps. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: In your example, could you could apply the expensiveMappingFunction after findFirst: Object first = list.stream().findFirst().map(expensiveMappingFunction).orElse(null);